# How to use a spinner within a fragment to change the contents of that fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I followed the [following tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html) to create an app with a material design tabbed interface with [the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvtKI.jpg).

My question is that in my TAB3 (a fragment) I have a `Spinner` at the top to change between 2 types of data view, a `ListView` and a `TableView` (diary).

I am a complete beginner programmer and I am not sure how to implement this. I have searched and know I cannot create a `Fragment` within a `Fragment`. I was thinking of communicating from the TAB3 `Fragment` to the parent `Activity` (though I'm not sure if this should be the `MainActivity` or the `ViewPagerAdaptor`) via an interface to swap out the TAB3 fragment to another one when selected with `FragmentManager`. Or is there a way I'm missing to swap out the `ListView` to a `TableLayout` on the fly within the `Fragment`?

I have searched much on this with my limited understanding and most tutorials can explain how to communicate from an activity to a fragment or fragment to fragment, but my situation seems a bit different in that all this exists within the TAB3 fragment and I don't know how to switch out a portion of that fragment.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, just make fragment in tab 3 as container and use nested fragments.

Comment: thank you so much, believe it or not this has been on my mind for weeks (pathetic i know) until i built up the courage to ask on here. just needed someone to point me in the right direction, thanks again!